# Three finger drag not working in Safari 10

Tags: trackpad, ui

I've noticed that three finger drag does not work in the latest Safari.

I used to be able to select text or pan in Google Maps easily. Now I have to push finger.

Outside Safari it works as usual.

I use BetterTouchTool if that makes any difference. Old school glass trackpad with click.

Comment: So is your question about BetterTouchTool not working properly or macOS not recognizing the gesture?

Comment: No. This is a built in OS X feature that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to update to the latest version of BetterTouchTool. Everything >= 1.86 should be compatible with Sierra.