# How do I turn on 3-finger drag on trackpad (Sierra)?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I originally set my trackpad to drag items when tapping on them with three fingers but it no longer works? How do I turn it back on?

Comment: This question is a bit vague.  There are [multiple 3-finger gestures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895).  Are you saying *none* of the 3-finger gestures work, only one of them doesn't or no gestures at all?  It's also helpful if you tell us what hardware you are using.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in Safari. Three finger drag works everywhere, except Safari: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253938/three-finger-drag-not-working-in-safari-10

Answer (score 25):

I think this is what your after…

1. Navigate to System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options.
2. Check the `Enable dragging` checkbox.
3. Select 'Three finger drag' from the dropdown.

Comment: But this is not available in new MacOs

Comment: @GiriPPoonati Yes it is. I just reformatted my macbook and installed Sierra fresh. Three finger drag used to be in the generic trackpad gesture settings but it has been moved into the "mouse & trackpad" options in the Accessibility menu. This answer is correct and worked great.

Comment: Ya the ThreeFinger drag is working now . Can u brief me the other options present over there like ' With and without Drag lock '